# Publishing from a CMS to CDS of different CMS

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have two different pair of CMS and CDS. One on the local network and one on the public domain. I am adding a new target type to CMS which is on local network. The properties of this new target type contain the httpuploadwebsite which is on the IIS of CDS which is in public domain.

Now when I am publishing I am getting the result as success but file is not reaching to CDS on Public domain. Also the Tridion Incoming Zip folder is empty.
Note:

1. CMS is different for both CDS.
2. One pair of CMS/CDS is on local network and other on public domain.

Suggest some solution.

Comment: I am getting following error in transport log:-                      ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute File retrieval on destination. What can be the reason?

Comment: Minor point, but I believe you mean `publication target` where you have `target type.`

Answer (score 7):

So in summary you are:

- Publishing from the local to public CDS stack from the local CMS
- Not knowingly receiving the published content on the public CDS

So in order to solve your problem you will, most likely, need to look at the configuration of the deployer on the Public CDS. If the Local CMS gives success on a publish when the Public CDS target is included, then it stands to reason that the Public CDS considers this as successful so most likely it is configuration.

The best way to check the configuration is to first look at the logs of your deployer that does not seem to be deploying. The logs will show you what configuration is being read and from there you should double check all the paths and settings of the configuration as well as resolving any issues being thrown in the logs.

You must note, as you were not explicit in your question, you cannot publish from two different Tridion CMS systems to the exact same CDS setup. By that I mean that if two CMS systems publish content to the same document root, content will overwrite because chances are content IDs are the same. So you must have completely separate deployers, configuration and document roots/database schemas.

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot Transport issues with an [HTTPUpload site](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_663JDNNNDHDH889595JDJDJD) (or [application](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_3E3A2FB1B4E34C20934B5A841C2E0930)), we can:

- **Attempt to visit the /HTTPUpload.aspx page from a browser**.

  - Connecting successfully will show `SDL Tridion ASPX HTTP Upload`.
  - .NET errors may hint at CD-side dll issues.
  - Time-outs, a 404, or other networking error may suggest connectivity or firewall problems.
- **Confirm the Default Application pool identity** has the [appropriate permissions](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_BE12DD5458854D87825159BA866299EE) (possibly `Network Service`, but confirm in IIS for your environment).
- **Check configs, logs, and incoming folder**.
- **Contact support**, preferably with the following:

  - Has this setup worked before and under what conditions
  - Configuration files
  - Any errors, stack traces
  - Details on the nature of the transport package (size, recent extension changes)

Be careful with misleading hints--just because incoming is empty doesn't mean something wasn't deployed or wasn't deployed somewhere else.

Though `publish` and `transport` troubleshooting may be similar, keep in mind that `Storage` is configurable--files, multimedia (binaries), and dynamic content can *`deployed`* to different locations/mediums.